# Two USB cams with one USB hub behave differently on two different laptops with same OS windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, matlab, hardware-acceleration, camera-raw

I have been trying to access two [USB cameras](http://www.elpcctv.com/h264-usb-cameras-c-85_102.html) through a USB hub (bought from local market). I am able to access both the cameras one after the other without any issue but when I tried to access both the cameras simultaneously I encounter an error as shown in the attached figure. I tried to test both USB cams with the hub on two laptops: one is Lenovo Z470 and the other is Dell Inspiron 14 series with a Windows 10 OS. I tried accessing them using the MATLAB function preview. I did not get any error on Lenovo Ideapad Z470, but I got an error on Dell Inspiron 14. I have attached the screenshot of the error:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4mKG.png) is the screen shot of the error message

MATLAB code :

```
v1 = videoinput('winvideo',1);

v2 = videoinput('winvideo',2);

preview(v1);  preview(v2);
```

I believe the USB ports might be differently configured for different Laptops/PC on most of the windows 10 and few windows 7 machines .

Comment: Are you using an externally powered hub? One of the laptops may not be supplying the same amperage as the other. A workaround may be to connect one to the hub and the other into the PC. Open device manager and click "view devices by connection". Drill down until you see the USB buses. Make sure each camera is on a separate bus.

Comment: @RandySchuman    I have Checked with an externally powered hub but it did not work. I can connect them individually to two different ports and they work perfectly fine. Even with the Hub that I have been using I could see both the cameras connected and I can access them individually but not simultaneously.